# How can I in plot graph involving complex numbers in Graphing Calculator 3D

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

According to the fundamental theorem of algebra, there are always exactly 'n' roots for an n-th degree polynomial. In the case of a quadratic equation, there are two roots. But sometimes the roots lie in complex plane, is there any way I can visualize this using Graphing Calculator 3D

Comment: Welcome to stackaxchange. That sais I'm voting to close this question   because it's not really about mathematics, it's about that particular device. (I think the answer to your question is "no").

Comment: Maybe relevant:https://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/files/articles/2000-2009/volume-45-2009/issue-3/vol45_no3_3.pdf